# Сериализация указателя

Tags: c++, сериализация

Пишу небольшую библиотеку для сериализации объекта (задали в универе) в xml файл. С обычными типами данных я разобрался и работает все хорошо. Но проблема заключается в сериализации указателя на целое число и указателя на экземпляр класса. Мне нужно их как-то сериализовать, чтобы после десериализации данные сохранились, т.е. указатели указывали на адрес того же значения.

Я думаю может при сериализации писать в атрибутах, что указатель указыват например на адрес переменной x, но как это лучше обыграть я не понимаю.

Подскажите какую-нибудь хорошую идею.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно при сериализации сохранять те данные, на которые указывает указатель, а при десериализации эти данные загружать.
Очевидно, что у вас не получится заставить (без дополнительных ухищрений) машину выделить память по тем же адресам, что были при другом запуске программы. Современные ОС намеренно рандомизуют адреса в программах, чтобы усложнить их взлом и реверс.

Дополнительной сложностью будет тот факт, что где-то в программе ваши указатели могут быть сохранены, например, связный список вы просто так не сохраните - развалится.

Отсюда следует, что не всегда структура данных после сериализации должна повторять структуру, которая хранится в памяти.

Ответьте для себя на такие вопросы:

- как я буду хранить массив
- как я буду хранить связный список
- как я буду хранить дерево
- как хранить std::map

Подскажу про связный список - нужно сохранить количество элементов и сами элементы, а при загрузке - создать связный список полностью заново, залив в него данные, выделив память под каждый элемент и настроив все указатели.

Еще одна идея - выделять для интов память в специальном массиве, а везде в программе хранить не указатели, а номера этих интов в том самом массиве - тогда, при некоторых обстоятельствах, у вас ничего не сломается.

Comment: Такие серьёзные структуры не будут выполняться. Я просто хочу как-нибудь придумать, чтобы int* a = &b и сериализовать (a), а чтобы потом после десериализации (a) и (b) все равно были как-то связаны. Т.е. нет конкретной задачи, чтобы адрес в памяти у переменных был один и тот же, что до сериализации.

Comment: Вот для этого и придется восстанавливать структуру данных заново, со всеми связями. Сейчас дополню ответ еще одной идеей

Comment: может стоит как-то в xml файле добавить какие-либо аттрибуты к указателям, чтобы упростить все?

Comment: Я понимаю, что структуры данных необходимо будет восстанавливать, я такую операцию делаю для контейнера vector. Но как быть с простым указателем?

Comment: Если в программе какой-то класс ссылается на сериализуемый, его тоже надо сериализовать. Корень "сериал" как раз и означает, что вы последовательно от корня обходите все сохраняемые сущности и пишете их в последовательность.

Comment: Простой указатель надо просто перезагрузить. Если у вас в программе есть сырые указатели, которые сохранены в других классах, у вас в программе, скорее всего, есть утечки памяти, потому что не ясно кто этим указателем владеет и когда он должен удаляться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99096/discussion-between-vitalja-b-and-gbg).

Comment: @VitaljaB., ваша идея *`"может стоит как-то в xml файле добавить какие-либо аттрибуты..."`* весьма плодотворна. Собственно, к каждой переменной можно добавить атрибут -- **адрес**. При десериализации строите таблицу соответствия старый-новый адреса и вновь размещаемым указателям меняете их значение (т.е. старый адрес переменной, на которую ссылается указатель) на новый адрес. Естественно, если переменная на которую ссылается десериализуемый указатель еще не размещена в памяти, то такие указатели надо запоминать и задавать им значение при десериализации соответствующей переменной